# important things to note for transition from wxWidgets to QT

Tags: c++, qt, wxwidgets

I'd like to pick up QT for some future projects and I would like to know, what are some important concepts to keep in mind when developing in QT? I can see the concept of signals and slots vs. wxwidget's events as something pretty important to get a good understanding of, so what other concept for QT are important that are not in wxWidgets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only real magic is signals/slots

There are a few other differences, Qt generally uses more modern C++ constructs than wx which is a bit more MFC era. But like most guis it's just a matter of learning the control->widget->window hierarchy.

It is worth getting the [Qt4 book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354160) or at least reading the free [Introduction to Design Patterns in C++ with Qt 4](http://cartan.cas.suffolk.edu/moin/OopDocbookWiki)

Depends on what platform you are using but check out [Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/) or if you are using MSVC the [qt-addin](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/visual-studio-add-in). The drag-drop dialog layout still isn't as nice as wxDesigner (IMHO) I usually endup coding most of the window, toolbar etc layout in c++

Answer (score 0):

There's a decent GUI designer for Qt. Compared to hand-coding, it's faster to use this during both initial development and maintenance.

Errors in signal-slot connections are detected at *run-time.*